# How can I add "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" to all the response headers from my web server

Tags: javascript, apache, http-headers, mime-types, httpresponse

I am running an apache web server. I would like to add "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" to all the response headers going from my web server. How can I do that? Is it possible to make changes to apache config files to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just append this to your webserver configuration, after making sure mod_headers is loaded:

```
<Directory "your_web_server_documents_directory">
    .......
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    .......
</Directory>
```

Comment: By "making sure mod_headers is loaded", do you mean just making sure "LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so" is NOT commented out in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 5):

what i did is this. i place the tags right after commented out property modules/mod_headers.so and restart my appserver but still the same response header.

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<Directory mod_headers.c>
     Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 5):

open your .htaccess and put this to prevent against XSS, Click-jacking and content-sniffing:

```
# Extra Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

reference: https://htaccessbook.com/increase-security-x-security-headers

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers did not work for you, it could be that the headers module does not exist in that path.
Try simply enabling it by running the following in your server's command line:

```
a2enmod headers
```

Then edit your configuration file `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` find the line that starts with `<Directory /var/www/>` or `<Directory /srv>`and inside it, add the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Remember to restart apache after, for the changes to take place.