# Spring MVC : X-Content-Type-Options problems, javascript not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem since 2-3 days. My javascript file is not loading anymore and i got an error with "X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff". (I dont even try to use this header, it might be added automatically)

I edited nothing in particular so i dont understand why this appears suddenly. 
I searched on internet but i did not find anyone with the same problem.

The code that includes the javascript file looks like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/lang/${js}_${pageContext.response.locale}.js"/>"></script>
```

As you can see, the file is loading dynamically.
I really dont know what details should i give you, feel free to ask.

What should i do in spring to correct this ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit:
This is the response header that I get from app_fr.js:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: fr
Content-Length: 635
Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 18:13:07 GMT
```

And the request header :

```
GET /lang/app_fr.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Cookie: Idea-afded334=6b807a5c-0afc-4400-a66c-2606b8247f4a; JSESSIONID=904C45361C1C62C6071576E49CAE8E8F
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" to all the response headers from my web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322295/how-can-i-add-x-content-type-options-nosniff-to-all-the-response-headers-from)

Comment: I think that Julien G. is getting this error because there is the "X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff" in the response header so this can not be helpful

Comment: Yes, i have the X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, but this should not be new because i never edited the conf file in tomcat.

Comment: Did you change the c:url value?

Comment: No i did not, why ? (${js}=app and ${pageContext.response.locale}=en(or other)) So the c:url looks like : <c:url value="/lang/app_en.js"/>

Comment: Can you show me the http headers of the response for this app_en.js ? the browser will refuse to load the styles and scripts in case they have an incorrect MIME-type. Maybe you need to change the type="text/javascript"

Comment: I'll show you the headers in 4 hours, i'm at work for the moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ! Thanks to Vasilis Vasilatos, i found the problem.

In my main jsp file (named app.jsp), i'm importing a dynamic generated javascript file (with a dynamic name that looks like : [page]_[locale].js, the dynamic name is for the cache system) like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/lang/${js}_${pageContext.response.locale}.js"/>"></script>
```

Inside my java code, when /lang/...js is invoked, the controller is generating localization values :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/lang/{param}")
    public ModelAndView localization(@PathVariable String param) {
        //generate your list from param
        return new ModelAndView("localization", "keys", list);
    }
```

The controller is finally calling the localization.jsp that looks like this :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

var Locale = [];
<c:forEach var="key" items="${keys}">
Locale["<spring:message text='${key}' javaScriptEscape='true'/>"] = "<spring:message code='${key}' javaScriptEscape='true' />";
</c:forEach>
```

As you can see, the first line contains the wrong thing : text/html instead of application/javascript. Replace it and it will work fine :)

PS: I still don't know why this happened suddenly. My localization system has been working for over 3 months...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the type="text/javascript" or replace with type="application/javascript"

Comment: Tried to replace with application/javascript & to remove, still not working :/ I edited my post to add request headers and response headers

Comment: As I can see in the  response headers you get Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8. This should be "application/javascript" or "text/javascript"

Comment: Try to add this in your web.xml: <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

Comment: This might be the problem indeed because other js files are loaded with the Content-Type: application/javascript. But when i add the mime-mapping in my tomcat conf web.xml, it's still text/html.

Comment: Can you check the character encoding of the other files and the app_fr.js? I think that because you used French characters maybe the default encoding of the file is changed and causes the problem.

Comment: Thank you Vasilis Vasilatos, the problem is now solved :) I posted an answer with the exact problem :)